# How to port WCF RESTful web service to Axis 2/C (or WSO C++)

Tags: wcf, web-services, apache-axis, axis2c

We are looking at redoing some web service applications (currently in prototype phase) from WCF/C# to a C++ cross platform web service framework.  So, I'm looking at Axis2/C or WSO2 WSF/C++ as possible frameworks.  I'd really like to port the functionality already written in the WCF service to the other service frameworks.

Here's the functionality:

- Web GET calls return JSON - supported by Axis2/Java (not sure about C/C++ versions yet)
- Can also return arbitrary content (like generated images or pages).

In WCF, you can return JSON by decorating the service operation like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/calltimings", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
TimingInfo[] CallTimings();
```

where TimingInfo is a simple data contract that serializes to JSON.  I can find how to do the same in Axis2 (Java version anyways).

The other call my webservice supports is:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/ping.htm")]
Stream PingHTML();
```

where the html page is generated dynamically.  There are other similar calls that return a `Stream` that contains the contents of generated images.  The WCF framework magically takes the Stream and puts the contents directly into the HTTP response body.  That is great for images, because I can write web client code like this:

```
<img id="viewportX" src="http://www.myservice.com/getimage?rotation=93"/>
```

So, my question is:  **How can I write an Axis2/C service operation that will return image content directly to the caller?**

How can I write this in the web client?

```
<img id="viewportX" src="http://www.myservice.com/axis2/some_service/getimage?rotation=93"/>
```

Can I?